# "Painful" vs. "hurtful"

Tags: word-choice

Can *painful* be used in place of *hurtful* as in the following sentence ?

> It is a painful story of a small baby fish I would not like to share with anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Painful* is **much more appropriate** than *hurtful* in your example sentence.

*Hurtful* carries a strong connotation that the hurt is deliberate, or at least callous.  *Painful* doesn’t carry this connotation at all.  Also, *hurtful* is mostly reserved for emotional or psychological pain, while *painful* can refer either to emotional or physical pain.

For instance, if someone makes a crude joke about cancer, that could be both *hurtful* and *painful*.  If someone gives a eulogy that vividly brings back memories of a departed friend, that might be *painful* for the listeners, but not *hurtful*.

Comment: Well, I am really sorry for not knowing much about these differences, and your post is very informative. By the way, I am no joker, I am a jokee. Thank you,

Comment: It's because *hurt* is normally used as a verb meaning *to inflict pain*, so "agent/intention" is much implied. Whereas *pain* can be felt in all sorts of situations that don't imply intentionality, even if it's possible to identify a cause.

Answer (score 5):

In common usage, "hurtful" has the connotation of the thing being referred to as intending to cause pain, rather than causing pain as an effect, where "painful" would be more likely to be used.

From your context, it sounds as if "hurtful" would *probably* not be the best word choice, unless the story of the fish, perhaps, was an allegorical story intended to point out the listener's character faults.

For example, the Shakespeare play *Hamlet* could be considered painful, as it might cause sadness in the audience.  However, the virtually identical play-within-the-play that is presented to the new king was hurtful, as it was intended to shame the king.

The recipient of a hurtful action would be "hurt".  The recipient of a painful action would be "in pain" (or less commonly, "pained"), but that really implies physical pain, not emotional.  You'd probably use a more specific word, like "saddnened", "sad" or "angry".

"It was hurtful when he called me a jerk.  He hurt me.  I was hurt."

"It was painful when I realized I was a jerk.  The realization saddened me.  I was sad."

Comment: Thank you wfaulk, "I am hurtful after reading your reply" and "I am painful after understanding your rhetorical remarks" are also correct uses (I make myself) ?

Comment: @Mark's Nemo:  No.  The reply was hurtful, not you.  You may have been hurt by it.  The construction for what you would be from a painful thing, though, would be "in pain", but that really implies physical pain.  I'll add more to the answer.

Comment: Good answer. In your final example, you could have said "The realization pained me", but I think I see why you shied away from that. "I was pained" would also be possible, but by then we're getting even further away from what people usually say.